# How to load css js from spring boot webflux?

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring-boot

I am studying spring boot webflux project.

I have succeeded in statically rendering html using thymeleaf.
Now I added a login page and added css and js, but when I actually rendered it, it was not reflected in the html.
In fact, css and js are displayed as 404 in browser tools.
Below are my codes.

```
--webConfig.java [src/main/java/com/author/projectname/configuratiopn]--
@EnableWebFlux
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements ApplicationContextAware, WebFluxConfigurer {
    
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ITemplateResolver thymeleafTemplateResolver() {
        final SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setApplicationContext(this.context);
        resolver.setPrefix("classpath:templates/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        resolver.setCheckExistence(false);
        return resolver;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/css/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/js/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/");
    }
    
    @Bean
    public SpringWebFluxTemplateEngine thymeleafTemplateEngine() 
    {
        SpringWebFluxTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringWebFluxTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(thymeleafTemplateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ThymeleafReactiveViewResolver thymeleafReactiveViewResolver() 
    {
        ThymeleafReactiveViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafReactiveViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(thymeleafTemplateEngine());
        return viewResolver;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) 
    {
        registry.viewResolver(thymeleafReactiveViewResolver());
    }
}
```

```
--login.html [src/main/resources/templates]--
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <header class="top-header">
        <title>Login Page</title>
        <link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{css/login.css}"/>
        <script type="application/javascript" th:src="@{js/login.js}"></script>
    </header>
    
    <div id="mainCoantiner">
      <div class="main-header">
        <div class="header-social">
        <ul>
          <li><a id="nmberone">1</a></li>
          <li><a id="nmbertwo">2</a></li>
          <li><a id="numberthree">3</a></li>
          <li><a>4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="folio-btn">
        <a class="folio-btn-item ajax" href="https://codepen.io/uiswarup/full/WNLdjqN" target="_blank"><span class="folio-btn-dot"></span><span class="folio-btn-dot"></span><span class="folio-btn-dot"></span><span class="folio-btn-dot"></span><span class="folio-btn-dot"></span><span class="folio-btn-dot"></span><span class="folio-btn-dot"></span><span class="folio-btn-dot"></span><span class="folio-btn-dot"></span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <!--dust particel-->
    <div>
      <div class="starsec"></div>
      <div class="starthird"></div>
      <div class="starfourth"></div>
      <div class="starfifth"></div>
    </div>
    <!--Dust particle end--->
    
    <div class="container text-center text-dark mt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 d-block mx-auto mt-5">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-md-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body wow-bg" id="formBg">
                  <h3 class="colorboard">Login</h3>
    
                  <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
    
                  <div class="input-group mb-3"> <input type="text" class="form-control textbox-dg" placeholder="Username"> </div>
                  <div class="input-group mb-4"> <input type="password" class="form-control textbox-dg" placeholder="Password"> </div>
    
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block logn-btn">Login</button> </div>
                    <div class="col-12"> <a href="https://codepen.io/uiswarup/full/WNLdjqN" class="btn btn-link box-shadow-0 px-0">Forgot password?</a> </div>
                  </div>
    
                  <div class="mt-6 btn-list">
                    <button type="button" class="socila-btn btn btn-icon btn-facebook fb-color"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f faa-ring animated"></i></button> <button type="button" class="socila-btn btn btn-icon btn-google incolor"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in faa-flash animated"></i></button> <button type="button" class="socila-btn btn btn-icon btn-twitter tweetcolor"><i class="fab fa-twitter faa-shake animated"></i></button> <button type="button" class="socila-btn btn btn-icon btn-dribbble driblecolor"><i class="fab fa-dribbble faa-pulse animated"></i></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

```
--login.css [src/main/resources/css]--
body
{
      background-color: #181828;
}

.top-header:before {
    background-image: url(https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-gxsOcYWghHA/Xp_izTh4sFI/AAAAAAAAU8s/y637Fwg99qAuzW9na_NT_uApny8Vce95gCEwYBhgL/s1600/header-footer-gradient-bg.png);
}
.top-header:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  opacity:0.5;
}

#mainCoantiner
{
    background-color: #181828;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.mystyleSec
{
  background-image: url(http://thepatternlibrary.com/img/h.jpg);
}

.mystylethird
{
background-image: url("https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/patterns/binding_dark.png");
}
/*************header*******/

.main-header {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(28, 31, 47, 0.16);
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #2e344d;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 36px rgb(0,0,0,0.5), -13px -13px 23px rgba(255,255,255, 0.03);
    border-width: 1px 0px 0 1px;
}

.folio-btn {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    right: 0;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}

.folio-btn-item {
position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    left: 15px;
    top: 15px;
}

.folio-btn-dot {
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    height: 33.3%;
    position: relative;
}

.folio-btn-dot:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 4px;
    height: 4px;
    margin: -2px 0 0 -2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
    transform: scale(1.0);
}

.folio-btn-dot:before
{
  background: #00BCD4;
}

.folio-btn:hover .folio-btn-dot:first-child:before, .folio-btn:hover .folio-btn-dot:nth-child(3):before, .folio-btn:hover .folio-btn-dot:nth-child(4):before, .folio-btn:hover .folio-btn-dot:nth-child(8):before {
    transform: scale(1.8);
    opacity: 0.5;
}


/***social***/
.header-social {
position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    width: auto;
    bottom: 17px;
    right: 90px;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 140px;
    box-shadow: 3px 9px 16px rgb(0,0,0,0.4), -3px -3px 10px rgba(255,255,255, 0.06), inset 14px 14px 26px rgb(0,0,0,0.3), inset -3px -3px 15px rgba(255,255,255, 0.05);
    border-width: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #2e344d;
}

.header-social:before
{
  background: #00BCD4;
}

.header-social:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: -3px;
    width: 36px;
    margin-left: -18px;
    height: 6px;
}

.header-social li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.header-social li a {
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-style: solid;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.41);
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.header-social li a:hover
{
  color:  #00BCD4;
  cursor:pointer;
}

ul, li
{
      border: none;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.main-header:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 120px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}

/***end*****/

.card{    border: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
background-color: #14edaa;}

.wow-bg
{
      background-color: #141421;
    border: 1px solid #2e2e4c;
    box-shadow: 3px 9px 16px rgb(0,0,0,0.4), -3px -3px 10px rgba(255,255,255, 0.06), inset 14px 14px 26px rgb(0,0,0,0.3), inset -3px -3px 15px rgba(255,255,255, 0.05);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 4px;
}



.starsec{
  content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    background: transparent;
   box-shadow: 571px 173px #00BCD4, 1732px 143px #00BCD4, 1745px 454px #FF5722, 234px 784px #00BCD4, 1793px 1123px #FF9800, 1076px 504px #03A9F4, 633px 601px #FF5722, 350px 630px #FFEB3B, 1164px 782px #00BCD4, 76px 690px #3F51B5, 1825px 701px #CDDC39, 1646px 578px #FFEB3B, 544px 293px #2196F3, 445px 1061px #673AB7, 928px 47px #00BCD4, 168px 1410px #8BC34A, 777px 782px #9C27B0, 1235px 1941px #9C27B0, 104px 1690px #8BC34A, 1167px 1338px #E91E63, 345px 1652px #009688, 1682px 1196px #F44336, 1995px 494px #8BC34A, 428px 798px #FF5722, 340px 1623px #F44336, 605px 349px #9C27B0, 1339px 1344px #673AB7, 1102px 1745px #3F51B5, 1592px 1676px #2196F3, 419px 1024px #FF9800, 630px 1033px #4CAF50, 1995px 1644px #00BCD4, 1092px 712px #9C27B0, 1355px 606px #F44336, 622px 1881px #CDDC39, 1481px 621px #9E9E9E, 19px 1348px #8BC34A, 864px 1780px #E91E63, 442px 1136px #2196F3, 67px 712px #FF5722, 89px 1406px #F44336, 275px 321px #009688, 592px 630px #E91E63, 1012px 1690px #9C27B0, 1749px 23px #673AB7, 94px 1542px #FFEB3B, 1201px 1657px #3F51B5, 1505px 692px #2196F3, 1799px 601px #03A9F4, 656px 811px #00BCD4, 701px 597px #00BCD4, 1202px 46px #FF5722, 890px 569px #FF5722, 1613px 813px #2196F3, 223px 252px #FF9800, 983px 1093px #F44336, 726px 1029px #FFC107, 1764px 778px #CDDC39, 622px 1643px #F44336, 174px 1559px #673AB7, 212px 517px #00BCD4, 340px 505px #FFF, 1700px 39px #FFF, 1768px 516px #F44336, 849px 391px #FF9800, 228px 1824px #FFF, 1119px 1680px #FFC107, 812px 1480px #3F51B5, 1438px 1585px #CDDC39, 137px 1397px #FFF, 1080px 456px #673AB7, 1208px 1437px #03A9F4, 857px 281px #F44336, 1254px 1306px #CDDC39, 987px 990px #4CAF50, 1655px 911px #00BCD4, 1102px 1216px #FF5722, 1807px 1044px #FFF, 660px 435px #03A9F4, 299px 678px #4CAF50, 1193px 115px #FF9800, 918px 290px #CDDC39, 1447px 1422px #FFEB3B, 91px 1273px #9C27B0, 108px 223px #FFEB3B, 146px 754px #00BCD4, 461px 1446px #FF5722, 1004px 391px #673AB7, 1529px 516px #F44336, 1206px 845px #CDDC39, 347px 583px #009688, 1102px 1332px #F44336, 709px 1756px #00BCD4, 1972px 248px #FFF, 1669px 1344px #FF5722, 1132px 406px #F44336, 320px 1076px #CDDC39, 126px 943px #FFEB3B, 263px 604px #FF5722, 1546px 692px #F44336;
  animation: animStar 150s linear infinite;
}

.starthird
{
  content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    background: transparent;
   box-shadow: 571px 173px #00BCD4, 1732px 143px #00BCD4, 1745px 454px #FF5722, 234px 784px #00BCD4, 1793px 1123px #FF9800, 1076px 504px #03A9F4, 633px 601px #FF5722, 350px 630px #FFEB3B, 1164px 782px #00BCD4, 76px 690px #3F51B5, 1825px 701px #CDDC39, 1646px 578px #FFEB3B, 544px 293px #2196F3, 445px 1061px #673AB7, 928px 47px #00BCD4, 168px 1410px #8BC34A, 777px 782px #9C27B0, 1235px 1941px #9C27B0, 104px 1690px #8BC34A, 1167px 1338px #E91E63, 345px 1652px #009688, 1682px 1196px #F44336, 1995px 494px #8BC34A, 428px 798px #FF5722, 340px 1623px #F44336, 605px 349px #9C27B0, 1339px 1344px #673AB7, 1102px 1745px #3F51B5, 1592px 1676px #2196F3, 419px 1024px #FF9800, 630px 1033px #4CAF50, 1995px 1644px #00BCD4, 1092px 712px #9C27B0, 1355px 606px #F44336, 622px 1881px #CDDC39, 1481px 621px #9E9E9E, 19px 1348px #8BC34A, 864px 1780px #E91E63, 442px 1136px #2196F3, 67px 712px #FF5722, 89px 1406px #F44336, 275px 321px #009688, 592px 630px #E91E63, 1012px 1690px #9C27B0, 1749px 23px #673AB7, 94px 1542px #FFEB3B, 1201px 1657px #3F51B5, 1505px 692px #2196F3, 1799px 601px #03A9F4, 656px 811px #00BCD4, 701px 597px #00BCD4, 1202px 46px #FF5722, 890px 569px #FF5722, 1613px 813px #2196F3, 223px 252px #FF9800, 983px 1093px #F44336, 726px 1029px #FFC107, 1764px 778px #CDDC39, 622px 1643px #F44336, 174px 1559px #673AB7, 212px 517px #00BCD4, 340px 505px #FFF, 1700px 39px #FFF, 1768px 516px #F44336, 849px 391px #FF9800, 228px 1824px #FFF, 1119px 1680px #FFC107, 812px 1480px #3F51B5, 1438px 1585px #CDDC39, 137px 1397px #FFF, 1080px 456px #673AB7, 1208px 1437px #03A9F4, 857px 281px #F44336, 1254px 1306px #CDDC39, 987px 990px #4CAF50, 1655px 911px #00BCD4, 1102px 1216px #FF5722, 1807px 1044px #FFF, 660px 435px #03A9F4, 299px 678px #4CAF50, 1193px 115px #FF9800, 918px 290px #CDDC39, 1447px 1422px #FFEB3B, 91px 1273px #9C27B0, 108px 223px #FFEB3B, 146px 754px #00BCD4, 461px 1446px #FF5722, 1004px 391px #673AB7, 1529px 516px #F44336, 1206px 845px #CDDC39, 347px 583px #009688, 1102px 1332px #F44336, 709px 1756px #00BCD4, 1972px 248px #FFF, 1669px 1344px #FF5722, 1132px 406px #F44336, 320px 1076px #CDDC39, 126px 943px #FFEB3B, 263px 604px #FF5722, 1546px 692px #F44336;
  animation: animStar 10s linear infinite;
}

.starfourth
{
  content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    background: transparent;
   box-shadow: 571px 173px #00BCD4, 1732px 143px #00BCD4, 1745px 454px #FF5722, 234px 784px #00BCD4, 1793px 1123px #FF9800, 1076px 504px #03A9F4, 633px 601px #FF5722, 350px 630px #FFEB3B, 1164px 782px #00BCD4, 76px 690px #3F51B5, 1825px 701px #CDDC39, 1646px 578px #FFEB3B, 544px 293px #2196F3, 445px 1061px #673AB7, 928px 47px #00BCD4, 168px 1410px #8BC34A, 777px 782px #9C27B0, 1235px 1941px #9C27B0, 104px 1690px #8BC34A, 1167px 1338px #E91E63, 345px 1652px #009688, 1682px 1196px #F44336, 1995px 494px #8BC34A, 428px 798px #FF5722, 340px 1623px #F44336, 605px 349px #9C27B0, 1339px 1344px #673AB7, 1102px 1745px #3F51B5, 1592px 1676px #2196F3, 419px 1024px #FF9800, 630px 1033px #4CAF50, 1995px 1644px #00BCD4, 1092px 712px #9C27B0, 1355px 606px #F44336, 622px 1881px #CDDC39, 1481px 621px #9E9E9E, 19px 1348px #8BC34A, 864px 1780px #E91E63, 442px 1136px #2196F3, 67px 712px #FF5722, 89px 1406px #F44336, 275px 321px #009688, 592px 630px #E91E63, 1012px 1690px #9C27B0, 1749px 23px #673AB7, 94px 1542px #FFEB3B, 1201px 1657px #3F51B5, 1505px 692px #2196F3, 1799px 601px #03A9F4, 656px 811px #00BCD4, 701px 597px #00BCD4, 1202px 46px #FF5722, 890px 569px #FF5722, 1613px 813px #2196F3, 223px 252px #FF9800, 983px 1093px #F44336, 726px 1029px #FFC107, 1764px 778px #CDDC39, 622px 1643px #F44336, 174px 1559px #673AB7, 212px 517px #00BCD4, 340px 505px #FFF, 1700px 39px #FFF, 1768px 516px #F44336, 849px 391px #FF9800, 228px 1824px #FFF, 1119px 1680px #FFC107, 812px 1480px #3F51B5, 1438px 1585px #CDDC39, 137px 1397px #FFF, 1080px 456px #673AB7, 1208px 1437px #03A9F4, 857px 281px #F44336, 1254px 1306px #CDDC39, 987px 990px #4CAF50, 1655px 911px #00BCD4, 1102px 1216px #FF5722, 1807px 1044px #FFF, 660px 435px #03A9F4, 299px 678px #4CAF50, 1193px 115px #FF9800, 918px 290px #CDDC39, 1447px 1422px #FFEB3B, 91px 1273px #9C27B0, 108px 223px #FFEB3B, 146px 754px #00BCD4, 461px 1446px #FF5722, 1004px 391px #673AB7, 1529px 516px #F44336, 1206px 845px #CDDC39, 347px 583px #009688, 1102px 1332px #F44336, 709px 1756px #00BCD4, 1972px 248px #FFF, 1669px 1344px #FF5722, 1132px 406px #F44336, 320px 1076px #CDDC39, 126px 943px #FFEB3B, 263px 604px #FF5722, 1546px 692px #F44336;
  animation: animStar 50s linear infinite;
}

.starfifth
{
  content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    background: transparent;
   box-shadow: 571px 173px #00BCD4, 1732px 143px #00BCD4, 1745px 454px #FF5722, 234px 784px #00BCD4, 1793px 1123px #FF9800, 1076px 504px #03A9F4, 633px 601px #FF5722, 350px 630px #FFEB3B, 1164px 782px #00BCD4, 76px 690px #3F51B5, 1825px 701px #CDDC39, 1646px 578px #FFEB3B, 544px 293px #2196F3, 445px 1061px #673AB7, 928px 47px #00BCD4, 168px 1410px #8BC34A, 777px 782px #9C27B0, 1235px 1941px #9C27B0, 104px 1690px #8BC34A, 1167px 1338px #E91E63, 345px 1652px #009688, 1682px 1196px #F44336, 1995px 494px #8BC34A, 428px 798px #FF5722, 340px 1623px #F44336, 605px 349px #9C27B0, 1339px 1344px #673AB7, 1102px 1745px #3F51B5, 1592px 1676px #2196F3, 419px 1024px #FF9800, 630px 1033px #4CAF50, 1995px 1644px #00BCD4, 1092px 712px #9C27B0, 1355px 606px #F44336, 622px 1881px #CDDC39, 1481px 621px #9E9E9E, 19px 1348px #8BC34A, 864px 1780px #E91E63, 442px 1136px #2196F3, 67px 712px #FF5722, 89px 1406px #F44336, 275px 321px #009688, 592px 630px #E91E63, 1012px 1690px #9C27B0, 1749px 23px #673AB7, 94px 1542px #FFEB3B, 1201px 1657px #3F51B5, 1505px 692px #2196F3, 1799px 601px #03A9F4, 656px 811px #00BCD4, 701px 597px #00BCD4, 1202px 46px #FF5722, 890px 569px #FF5722, 1613px 813px #2196F3, 223px 252px #FF9800, 983px 1093px #F44336, 726px 1029px #FFC107, 1764px 778px #CDDC39, 622px 1643px #F44336, 174px 1559px #673AB7, 212px 517px #00BCD4, 340px 505px #FFF, 1700px 39px #FFF, 1768px 516px #F44336, 849px 391px #FF9800, 228px 1824px #FFF, 1119px 1680px #FFC107, 812px 1480px #3F51B5, 1438px 1585px #CDDC39, 137px 1397px #FFF, 1080px 456px #673AB7, 1208px 1437px #03A9F4, 857px 281px #F44336, 1254px 1306px #CDDC39, 987px 990px #4CAF50, 1655px 911px #00BCD4, 1102px 1216px #FF5722, 1807px 1044px #FFF, 660px 435px #03A9F4, 299px 678px #4CAF50, 1193px 115px #FF9800, 918px 290px #CDDC39, 1447px 1422px #FFEB3B, 91px 1273px #9C27B0, 108px 223px #FFEB3B, 146px 754px #00BCD4, 461px 1446px #FF5722, 1004px 391px #673AB7, 1529px 516px #F44336, 1206px 845px #CDDC39, 347px 583px #009688, 1102px 1332px #F44336, 709px 1756px #00BCD4, 1972px 248px #FFF, 1669px 1344px #FF5722, 1132px 406px #F44336, 320px 1076px #CDDC39, 126px 943px #FFEB3B, 263px 604px #FF5722, 1546px 692px #F44336;
  animation: animStar 80s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animStar
{
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-2000px);
}
}



.logn-btn
{
     background: #1c1f2f;
    border-radius: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #2e344d;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    /* box-shadow: 10px 10px 36px rgb(0,0,0,0.5), -13px -13px 23px rgba(255,255,255, 0.03), inset 14px 14px 70px rgb(0,0,0,0.2), inset -15px -15px 30px rgba(255,255,255, 0.04); */
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 26px rgb(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 7px 13px rgba(255,255,255, 0.03);
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.logn-btn:hover
{
  background-color: #1c1f2f;
    border-radius: 50px;
    min-width: 140px;
    /* box-shadow: 10px 10px 36px rgb(0,0,0,0.5), -13px -13px 23px rgba(255,255,255, 0.03), inset 14px 14px 70px rgb(0,0,0,0.2), inset -15px -15px 30px rgba(255,255,255, 0.04); */
    box-shadow: 3px 9px 16px rgb(0,0,0,0.4), -3px -3px 10px rgba(255,255,255, 0.06), inset 14px 14px 26px rgb(0,0,0,0.3), inset -3px -3px 15px rgba(255,255,255, 0.05);
    border-width: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #2e344d;
}

.textbox-dg
{
  background: rgba(28, 31, 47, 0.16);
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #2e344d;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    /* box-shadow: 10px 10px 36px rgb(0,0,0,0.5), -13px -13px 23px rgba(255,255,255, 0.03), inset 14px 14px 70px rgb(0,0,0,0.2), inset -15px -15px 30px rgba(255,255,255, 0.04); */
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 36px rgb(0,0,0,0.5), -13px -13px 23px rgba(255,255,255, 0.03);
    border-width: 1px 0px 0 1px;
      margin-top: 15px;
}



.form-control:focus
{
  border: 1px solid #344d2e;
  color: #495057;
    outline: 0;
    background: rgb(17, 20, 31);
    border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    /* box-shadow: 10px 10px 36px rgb(0,0,0,0.5), -13px -13px 23px rgba(255,255,255, 0.03), inset 14px 14px 70px rgb(0,0,0,0.2), inset -15px -15px 30px rgba(255,255,255, 0.04); */
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 36px rgb(0,0,0,0.5), -13px -13px 23px rgba(255,255,255, 0.03);
}



.btn-link {
    color: #344d2e;
}


.btn-link:hover {
    color: #2b7a19;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, .show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #807f7f;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: #2b7a19;
}


.btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 255, 110, 0.25);
}

.mt-6, .my-6 {
    margin-top: 2rem !important;
}


.socila-btn
{
  height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    width: 40px;
    box-shadow: 3px 9px 16px rgb(0,0,0,0.4), -3px -3px 10px rgba(255,255,255, 0.06), inset 14px 14px 26px rgb(0,0,0,0.3), inset -3px -3px 15px rgba(255,255,255, 0.05);
    border-width: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.2);
    margin-right: 10px;
   
}

.fb-color
{
  color:#3b5998 ;
}

.incolor
{
  color:#007bff;
}

.tweetcolor
{
  color:#41a4f7;
}
.driblecolor
{
  color:#e83e8c;
}

.colorboard
{
  color: #00ffaaed;
}
```

```
--login.js [src/main/resources/js]--

$('#nmberone').click(function() {
    $('#mainCoantiner, #formBg').removeClass('mystyleSec');
  $('#mainCoantiner, #formBg').removeClass('mystylethird');
  event.stopPropagation();
});



$('#nmbertwo').click(function() {
   $('#mainCoantiner, #formBg').removeClass('mystylethird');
    $('#mainCoantiner, #formBg').addClass('mystyleSec');
  event.stopPropagation();
});


$('#numberthree').click(function() {
   /* $('#catbox').removeClass('cat2');*/
    $('#mainCoantiner, #formBg').addClass('mystylethird');
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I read several articles on the Internet and saw some solutions on this site, but it didn't work.
The presumed problem is thought to be a problem with thymeleaf settings. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem!
In the following way

1. Add the code below to Router(@controller).

```
@Bean
    RouterFunction<ServerResponse> staticResourceRouter()
    {
        return RouterFunctions.resources("/**", new ClassPathResource("static/"));
    }
```

2. Check the results and the operation is complete!

It was a rudimentary question, and I think it was because I didn't look for enough information. I will study hard to move forward. thank you